# how do you get the background colour from a style sheet using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a web program that can change stylesheets (don't ask), I need to get the background-color property value for a class using jquery.
The class(es) are like below, but each style sheet will have a different colour.

DIV.row.error DIV.field INPUT.input-field

{
    background: #fbdad8;
    border:1px #ef4035 solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
    -o-border-radius: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
}

I have tried using the code before, but it is always white, any ideas?

```
      var checked = $('#<%=chkTermsAgreed.ClientID %>').attr('checked');
      var toChange = $('#<%=lblTermsAgreed.ClientID %>')

      if (!checked) {

          var bgColor = $('<div class=\"row error\"><input class=\"input-field\"/></div>').hide().appendTo("body");
          bgColor = bgColor.find('.input-field');
          toChange.css('background-color', bgColor.css('background-color'));
          bgColor.remove();
       }
```

Comment: By stylesheets, are you talking about accessing external stylesheets with `document.styleSheets`, and parsing the external file to get a css value, or are you talking about styles that have been applied to elements that can be gotten with the regular jQuery css() function ?

Comment: Whatever gives me the value #fbdad8 from the example. I would have thought it would be more efficient to create the class in the dom than to parse the external stylesheet. The other issue to add is that I will not know the name of the stylesheet is, as it is processed and pumped out from the server side.

Comment: You don't have to parse them : they're already parsed by the browser and you don't need to know their name (see answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I see enabling to get the background-color even if no element of the class is present is reading the stylesheets in js.

The good news is they are browsable objects and it's efficient to read them as they're yet parsed.

You can iterate for example on all rules like this in order to find your background-color :

```
for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        var cssRules = styleSheet.rules; // chrome, IE
        if (!cssRules) cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules; // firefox
        for (var j=0; j<cssRules.length; j++) {
            var rule = cssRules[j];
            console.log(styleSheet.href, rule);
            if (rule.selectorText=="DIV.row.error DIV.field INPUT.input-field") {
                console.log('found it : ', rule.style.getPropertyValue('background-color'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you're trying to get background-color style of `$('div.row.error input[class="input-field"]')` class. This problem solves itself when you clarify what you want to get:

- **class** selectors suffice to tag names without space
- You can select an element **with** an attribute by tag[attribute="value"] selector
- If you suffice a space and enter a new selector whilst writing your main selector; you **find** sub selectors of former.
- If you select an element or a group **with** a class you can change or get any attribute of it.

Now let's code.
Here is my proposal:

```
var checked = $('#<%=chkTermsAgreed.ClientID %>').attr('checked');
var toChange = $('#<%=lblTermsAgreed.ClientID %>');
var source = $('div.row.error input[class="input-field"]');

if (!checked) {
    toChange.css('background-color', source.css('background-color'));
}
```

I tried the selector in inspector. It works.
Hope this helps.
Cheers.